# Results are not showing after installing

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

I have installed the Nominatim on openSUSE

i got the 2.3 version

```
wget http://www.nominatim.org/release/Nominatim-2.3.0.tar.bz2
```

and i have build the source as below

```
cd Nominatim
 ./configure
 make
```

and i want to test so not downloaded all the wiki and UK codes
just started with india pbf file

by importing

```
./utils/setup.php --osm-file india.pbf --all 2>&1 | tee setup.log
```

and i setup the website

```
./utils/setup.php --create-website /var/www/nominatim
```

restarted apache server

everything is fine till here, while testing when i request

```
http://nominatim.mydomain.com/search.php?q=Bangalore&format=xml&polygon=1&addressdetails=1
```

no results is showing.

i am not able to find the log.

even enabled log in setting.php as below

```
@define('CONST_Debug', true);
@define('CONST_Log_DB', true);
@define('CONST_Log_File', true);
@define('CONST_Log_File_SearchLog', '/var/log/nominatim-search.log');
@define('CONST_Log_File_ReverseLog', '/var/log/nominatim-reverse.log');
```

Help me where i can find what is going wrong

Comment: Have you loaded any data? You need to provide some more information, like what you did and what you've looked at.

Comment: added the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is issue with the web server apache2 configuration

After fixing that basically i re installed apache-mod_php then it started giving error with DB connection

full details of this is in [Github issue](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/issues/196)